# Signup/login with Google plus in Titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I want to integrate Google+ sign up and login functionality in my app in Titanium that can be used to login on Android and iOS platforms. I searched for a solution but that didn't work out. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: you can check [this google auth module](https://github.com/ejci/Google-Auth-for-Titanium)

Comment: Yup. I checked. It is for login with Google. I need it for Google plus. Will it work for that too?

Comment: This same module can also be used for Google+ also(because of same oauth process), you have to just enable google+ api from google console.